# Regex scraping with overlapping

Tags: regex

I have been banging my head at this question for too long. My current project is to scrape files and search for keywords through HTML files. I cannot use simplephpdom library for reason that are not related to this question.

I need to scrape words from html tags. So if I am searching for `stack` 
it should not match `<a class="stack"> test <a>` It should only match within tags
 `<a class="test"> stack <a>`

I developed the following regex `(?:>[^><]*)keyword(?:[^><]*</)`
This regex works... but only 1 keyword is found per tag. In example the following will only grab the first `stack` and bail : `<h1> Stack is so awesome. Stack is here again</h1>`

Question. How to search for keyword within HTML tags. Not grab meta data or html data.

Comment: You should parse the HTML with an HTML parser. Then, it is a child's play.

Comment: i would of , but the files are PHP and i cannot parse that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on what was posted, try this pattern

```
(stack)(?![^<>]*>)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/336)

Comment: Wait a second... Please answer me this. Can lookaheads have regex? Because I thought lookarounds are only literals, or is that just lookbehinds?

Comment: look-arounds may have regex patterns, look-behind has to be fixed width for most engines but can be regex.